# Connecting to remote daemon in testnet is not working

Tags: daemon, testnet, transfer

I'm studying blockchain and alt coins like Monero. I want to see how transaction works in Monero network because they are all behind the veils. So, I tried to create a testnet account to test transactions, and I finally get XMR on testnet with mining.

But whenever I transfer the coin to my another account on testnet, my wallet says "**Error: no connection to daemon. Please make sure daemon is running**.".

I opened cli-wallet with using option "**./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-host testnet.xmrchain.net:28081 --testnet --trusted-daemon**" with using XMRChain daemon.

I think the argument I entered is correct because I can do mining the blocks in the testnet. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

the current code on testnet.xmrchain.net does not allow transfers (it's a bug which is fixed but not yet deployed there). just run your own testnet node.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I downloaded full node to run the testnet and it worked!

Comment: Any update on this? Can I use testnet.xmrchain.net now?